# Lightning Component Attribute

Tags: lightning, attribute

I have a lightning component with a child component. I'm passing an array of object to the child. It seemed that there was an attribute that I could set to invoke a function once the child attribute was loaded. I thought is was named something on the line of "?afterloading?" or sort. I can't seem to find documentation anymore. I'm using a change handler to handle the situation but this is for a piece of mind.

I thought I could do something as follow:

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute name="foo" type="object[]" afterloading="{!c.dosomething}">
</aura:component>
```

Comment: "I can't seem to find documentation anymore" ?

Comment: can't find in the documentation. I am most def need more coffee. I am confusing with afterscriptsloaded.

Comment: I think a changehandler is totally the right way to do it - it's not a workaround

Answer (score 2):

The only attributes for attributes are listed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_attribute.htm). They are:

- access
- name
- type
- default
- required
- description

And no, you're not missing anything; you'd use an aura:valueChange listener, as you're doing, to listen for changes. You were most likely thinking about `afterScriptsLoaded` on the `ltng:require` component, which would be used to call some initialization script after loading external libraries.